# How to lower the objects amount in ListObject and GetObject when Power Bi Refreshing dataset at AWS S3 (through ODBC connect)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, powerbi

im using Power BI to visualize the Data in AWS S3 through Athena-ODBC connection.

The connection is fine and now after one year running. Now i need to lower the object amount in "ListObject" and "GetObject" whenever Power BI refreshing the database after the data accumulate a lot.

Any suggected method to lower the objects ammount in such action ???
sorry for question might be silly as im new comer for AWS and Power BI.

i have try to put a filter at query Advanced Editor in Power BI to filter in only 30 days data:
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [localtime] >= DateTime.LocalNow() - #duration(30, 0, 0, 0))

But the filter seem have no effect on "ListObject" and "GetObject" ammount, it still count all object and folder in the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

i try to use the "Incremantal Refresh" in PBI to avoid the full scan of S3 by PBI data refreshing. Because my dataset have not include a column for "Data/time" format, i cannot success to use these "incremantal refresh", and each refreshing still fully scan the S3 bucket.

with reading some question in here, i modify the data source from "odbc.datasource" to "odbc.query" and put a where clause in the query to filter the data set through partition (YYYY,MM,DD,HH) in the data set. the where clause success fold to AWS Athena, and limit the PBI refreshing to certain fold in the bucket.

Here is my query:

```
let
NowDateTime = DateTime.LocalNow(),
RangeStart = Date.AddDays(NowDateTime, -Number.From(DataDuration)),
StartYear = Text.From(Date.Year(RangeStart)),
StartMonth = if Date.Month(RangeStart) >= 10 then 
Text.From(Date.Month(RangeStart)) else 
Text.PadStart(Text.From(Date.Month(RangeStart)), 2, "0"),
StartDay = Text.PadStart(Text.From(Date.Day(RangeStart)), 2, "0"),
EndYear = Text.From(Date.Year(NowDateTime)),
EndMonth = if Date.Month(NowDateTime) >= 10 then 
Text.From(Date.Month(NowDateTime)) else 
Text.PadStart(Text.From(Date.Month(NowDateTime)), 2, "0"),
EndDay = Text.PadStart(Text.From(Date.Day(NowDateTime)), 2, "0"),
Source =
        if EndYear > StartYear or (EndYear = StartYear and EndMonth > StartMonth) then
        Odbc.Query("dsn=dsn_name", "SELECT * FROM Catalog_name.DataBbase_name.table_name WHERE " &
        "((partition_0 = '" & StartYear & "' AND partition_1 = '" & StartMonth & "' AND partition_2 >= '" & StartDay & "') OR " &
        "(partition_0 = '" & StartYear & "' AND partition_1 > '" & StartMonth & "') OR " &
        "(partition_0 > '" & StartYear & "' AND partition_0 < '" & EndYear & "') OR " &
        "(partition_0 = '" & EndYear & "' AND partition_1 < '" & EndMonth & "') OR " &
        "(partition_0 = '" & EndYear & "' AND partition_1 = '" & EndMonth & "' AND partition_2 <= '" & EndDay & "'))")
    else
        Odbc.Query("dsn=dsn_name", "SELECT * FROM Catalog_name.DataBbase_name.table_name WHERE " &
        "(partition_0 = '" & StartYear & "' AND partition_1 = '" & StartMonth & "' AND partition_2 >= '" & StartDay & "' AND partition_2 <= '" & EndDay & "')")
```

i have create a parameter to set the Data Duration, and the where clause might still need to modiy but it can query in Athena